# How do I properly input an else function?

Tags: python

else function on line 21 is failing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tide.png)

https://github.com/ksu-is/NameGen/blob/master/namegen.py

need some tips to make this run properly thank you!

Comment: Please provide the code in the post, format it with the {} brackets symbol in the post edit taskbar.

Comment: row 48-50 looks somewhat confusing and row 40 is wrong. as for naming, skip "the".

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the user enters alphabets characters (.isalpha()), so any word that contains only letters will pass the if statement and break the loop, your not checking whether the input is only 'boy' or 'girl' as you suggests: you can do:

```
if baby_gender.lower() in ["boy", "girl"]:
```

You can omit the .lower() functions if you want, this would simply ensure that if the user enters "Boy" or "boY" or any other case will match.

hope this help